# Comparisons to table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

So I have been working with queries for a couple of years,
and some sometimes I ask myself if there isn't a simpler way,
or a more sophisticated way to make it work. So today I came across a situation where I have a table, let's say **users**, and I want to make several comparisons to that table.

In this case get a statistic from every user that i have: to know how many orders he made, or how many products he has in the wishlist for a specified period(s) of time; for example last week and this week.
So what I want to know is if the best way is to use `left joins`, and `ifs` like this:

```
SELECT 
users.id,
SUM(IF(wishlist.date = LAST_WEEK, 1, 0)) LAST_WEEK_WISHLIST,
SUM(IF(wishlist.date = THIS_WEEK, 1, 0)) THIS_WEEK_WISHLIST,
SUM(IF(orders.date = LAST_WEEK, 1, 0)) LAST_WEEK_ORDERS,
SUM(IF(orders.date = THIS_WEEK, 1, 0)) THIS_WEEK_ORDERS
FROM
users
LEFT JOIN wishlist ON users.id = wishlist.user_id
LEFT JOIN orders ON users.id = orders.user_id
... 
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY users.id ASC
```

...or is there a better or more optimized way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 3 tables, plus tell us how big the tables are.  Also, is the older data 'static'?  That is, can we summarize old data and only have to 'compute' the current data?

Comment: CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  display_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  password CHAR(41) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX (email)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

Comment: CREATE TABLE wishlist(
   user_id INT NOT NULL,
   product_id INT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (product_id)
)

Comment: CREATE TABLE orders
(
id int NOT NULL,
pid int NOT NULL,
order_number int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT fk_orders_users FOREIGN KEY (pid)
REFERENCES users(id)
)

Comment: 80 for email?  Likely to be truncated for someone.

Comment: I don't see any field called `LAST_WEEK`.

Comment: LAST_WEEK is like a variable, a real date ou interval of dates to be exact. Just an example.

Comment: Adding `WHERE orders.date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND ...` would make it run faster.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend trying to use sub queries rather than joining this may make a difference

Here is an example of how I solved this

```
SELECT l_outer.Locations_LocationID, l_outer.Locations_LocationName,

ifnull((SELECT format(sum(replace(Payments_Amount, '$', '')), 2) as card_total
    FROM Payments as p
    where p.Payments_PaymentItem in ('Visa', 'MasterCard', 'Discover') AND p.Payments_LocationID = l_outer.Locations_LocationID AND STR_TO_DATE(Payments_Date, '%m/%d/%Y') >= DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL (DAY(curdate())-1) DAY)
    group by p.Payments_LocationID), 0.00) Cards,

ifnull((SELECT format(sum(replace(Payments_Amount, '$', '')), 2) as AmericanExpress_total
    FROM Payments as p
    where p.Payments_PaymentItem = 'American Express' AND p.Payments_LocationID = l_outer.Locations_LocationID AND STR_TO_DATE(Payments_Date, '%m/%d/%Y') >= DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL (DAY(curdate())-1) DAY)
    group by p.Payments_LocationID), 0.00) AmericanExpress

From Locations as l_outer
```